# Superfluous use of //, or necessary

Tags: perl

I have come across the following legacy code:

```
sub some_func {
    my $val = $ENV{some_key} // '';
    if ( length($val) ) {
        return $val;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Usually I would dismiss this as convoluted and rewrite as:

```
sub some_func {
    return $ENV{some_key} || 0;
}
```

but the programmer who wrote this was pretty good. Am I missing something?

Comment: afaict the only difference between the two is whether '0' or 0 is returned when the environment variable is '0'.

Comment: Is that really a `//` in the original code, or is it supposed to be `||`.  The latter makes more sense.  But, since you're looking at ENV vars, I'd think empty strings would be better than 0's, so something like `return $ENV{some_key} || "";` might work better.

Comment: @jimtut, `//` makes perfect sense. It silences the undef warning `length` gives in Perls earlier than 5.12. It's another way of doing `my $val = $ENV{some_key}; if (defined($val) && length($val))`.  (Using `||` in the first snippet only makes sense in the sense that it effectively equivalent to `//` in the first snippet.)

Comment: Somehow, I was unaware of this logical operation!  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Original:

- Empty string ⇒ zero (as a number)
- String zero ⇒ zero (as a string)
- Number zero ⇒ zero (as a number)
- Undefined ⇒ zero (as a number)

Everything else returns $ENV{some_key}

---

Rewrite:

- Empty string ⇒ zero (as a number)
- String zero ⇒ zero (as a number)
- Number zero ⇒ zero (as a number)
- Undefined ⇒ zero (as a number)

Everything else returns $ENV{some_key}

---

So there's a minor difference that's not suppose to matter, but it does in some cases (e.g. `encode_json`). Still, I think the difference is unintentional.